# Fixing Nginx Django uWSGI proxy timeout error

Tags: django, nginx, timeout, wsgi

Nginx proxy is sending a timeout on 60sec even though timeout is set on higher values. How can I force a no-timeout or a >60sec timeout. My conf file for nginx is:

```
server {
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';

proxy_connect_timeout 9000s;
proxy_send_timeout 9000s;
proxy_read_timeout 9000s;
listen 8080;

location /static {
    alias /vol/static;
}

location / {

    include /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass toolsportal:8000;
 
    proxy_buffers 8 16k; # Buffer pool = 8 buffers of 16k ·fixes large cookie 502https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/605467/how-to-handle-a-too-large-cookie-causing-nginx-to-return-a-502
    proxy_buffer_size 16k; # 16k of buffers from pool used for headers
    proxy_connect_timeout 9000s;
    proxy_send_timeout 9000s;
    proxy_read_timeout 9000s;
    send_timeout 9000s;
    client_body_timeout 9000s;
    uwsgi_socket_keepalive on;
    uwsgi_send_timeout 3600s;
    uwsgi_read_timeout 3600s;
}
```

}

Where "toolsportal" is the Django app service

Nginxlog on startup:

```
/docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will 

attempt to perform configuration
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: can not modify /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf (read-only file system?)
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
2022/03/02 15:08:16 [notice] 1#1: using the "epoll" event method
2022/03/02 15:08:16 [notice] 1#1: nginx/1.21.4
2022/03/02 15:08:16 [notice] 1#1: built by gcc 10.3.1 20211027 (Alpine 10.3.1_git20211027)
2022/03/02 15:08:16 [notice] 1#1: OS: Linux 5.4.0-1045-aws
2022/03/02 15:08:16 [notice] 1#1: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1048576:1048576
2022/03/02 15:08:16 [notice] 1#1: start worker processes
2022/03/02 15:08:16 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 23
2022/03/02 15:08:16 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 24
2022/03/02 15:08:16 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 25
2022/03/02 15:08:16 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 26
```

Comment: Did you check nginx logs ?

Comment: Not sure how. I'm new on this

Comment: @AnkitTiwari edit with log

Comment: try to add this in your gunicorn file `gunicorn wsgi:application --timeout 300`

Comment: @AnkitTiwari im using uwsgi no gunicorn. But will search equivalent

Comment: try this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16141610/nginx-timeouts-when-uwsgi-takes-long-to-process-request) this should help you